# How to check value exist inside 2D array with Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, kotlin, comparison, equality

I'm trying to find if an array exists inside a 2D array using `contains(...)` but even though it is in the array the return value is `false`. Why and how can I make it work?

```
val obs = arrayOf (arrayOf(5, 5),arrayOf(4, 2),arrayOf(2, 3))
println(obs.contains(arrayOf(2, 3))) // false

val obs1 = arrayListOf (arrayListOf(5, 5), arrayListOf(4, 2), arrayListOf(2, 3))
println(obs1.contains(arrayListOf(2, 3))) // true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obs.contains(arrayOf(2,3))` will only yield true if the reference of `arrayOf(2,3)` is equal to any of the references in `obs`. in other words, it's resorting to *reference* equality **for arrays** instead of *content* equality.

You can get the result you require by using *contentEquals*:

```
println(obs.any { it.contentEquals(arrayOf(2,3)) }) // true
```

The second version prints as expected because collections are compared *structurally*.

---

You may find [What you didn’t know about arrays in Kotlin](https://medium.com/asos-techblog/what-you-didnt-know-about-arrays-in-kotlin-d3b20337e4) of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break the loop down to an individual comparison. What basically happens is a comparison like this:

```
arrayOf(2, 3) == arrayOf(2, 3) // yields false

arrayListOf(2, 3) == arrayListOf(2, 3) // yields true
```

`arrayOf(...)` creates an `kotlin.Array` and `arrayListOf(...)` an `kotlin.collections.ArrayList`.

When you call `contains(...)` of `Array` it will check for the reference of its values, which is obviously different, since the constructor is called twice yielding a new reference each time.

When you call `contains(...)` of `ArrayList` it will check for the contents of its values, which is indeed the same.

**Side note:**

If you type `arrayOf(2, 3) == arrayOf(2, 3)` in IntelliJ it will even warn you

> Dangerous array comparison

and the tip to fix it is to replace `==` with `contentEquals`. Since you want to do it for multiple elements in your array you have to do this for each element (at least until there is a match) for example using `any`.

So, we arrive at what [Aomine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5862071/aomine) already concluded:

```
obs.any { it.contentEquals(arrayOf(2,3)) }
```